# how to build atom on a disconnected redhat linux 7.7 system

Tags: node.js, atom-editor, redhat

I am running redhat 7.7 64 bit. I have node 12.16.3 installed. The machine I am building on is not connected to the internet and can not be for security reasons. I get the following error when I run script/build in the unzipped atom directory. It looks to me like it is trying to reach out for something from github. Anyway to build this with out a network connection?

```
jgaer@ljgaer2_~/atom-master: script/build

fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

/home/jgaer/atom-master/script/lib/spawn-sync.js:17
 `Command ${result.args.join(' ')} exited with code "${result.status}"`  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined  at module.exports (/home/jgaer/atom-master/script/lib/spawn-sync.js:17:30)
 at computeAppVersion (/home/jgaer/atom-master/script/config.js:95:20)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jgaer/atom-master/script/config.js:24:28)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
 at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
 at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jgaer/atom-master/script/bootstrap:6:16)
```

Comment: Sounds like a pretty obvious error? Did you set the `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM` environment variable? Also, some google shows a number of posts about that error, https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211078 in particular seems quite useful (with a comment on editing the Makefile, which I assume atom has, too). Having said that, did you ask this on the [atom issue tracker](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues)? Because as a build bug, that's really the _first_ place to file this (after searching the open and closed issues to see if this already has a known solution).

Comment: I tried setting GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM to true. It eliminated the message about the variable being set but not the errors further down the line. I did start with the  atom issue tracker. https://github.com/atom/atom/discussions/22568. That got me past the first problem which was the version of node that I was using, but no response since I posted this as a  followup. Thank you for the bbs link, that looks promising.

Comment: note that the current recent LTS is Node 14, though. If you're upgrading, it makes a lot more sense to upgrade to 14 rather than 12 (which is at this point kind of horribly out of date with respect to JS features it supports. It can't even do import/export without experimental runtime flags).

Answer (score 0):

Use *Git bash* to do this, it worked in my case at least.